# Single Sign on with Apache Shiro and Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat7, single-sign-on, shiro

I have two separate maven modules: One of them is a rest application, and the other a web app.

They run on the same tomcat 7 server, deployed as different wars, and use Shiro for authentication and authorization.

Since the web application needs to make ajax calls to the rest services, I thought it would be nice to add this SSO thing to both applications. So as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26875767), I made the necessary changes to the modules, hoping it would be an easy task, but it wasn't to me. I can authenticate in each application separately, but cannot manage to make them share the session info. Every time I log in the web app and try to access a rest service, I'm redirected to the rest service login page, and vice-versa.

Here is the shiro.ini content for the web app:

```
[main]

credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256

dataSource = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
dataSource.user = ****
dataSource.password = ****
dataSource.port = ****
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:****/****
dataSource.databaseName = ****

jdbcRealm = com.camacua.shiro.realm.SaltAwareJdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.saltStyle = COLUMN
jdbcRealm.saltedAuthenticationQuery = select password, password_salt, userId from AccountInfo where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role_name from AccountInfo_Role where accountInfo_username = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = select permission_name from Role_Permission where role_name = ?
securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = SSOcookie
cookie.path = /
cookie.domain = localhost
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
cacheManager.cacheManagerConfigFile = classpath:ehcache.xml
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

securityManager.sessionMode = native

#Para testing:
ssl.enabled=false

shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp

[urls]
/css/**=anon
/img/**=anon
/logout = logout
/** = ssl,authc
```

And the shiro.ini file for the rest app:

```
[main]
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256

dataSource = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
dataSource.user = ****
dataSource.password = ****
dataSource.port = ****
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:****/****
dataSource.databaseName = ****

jdbcRealm = com.camacua.shiro.realm.SaltAwareJdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.saltStyle = COLUMN
jdbcRealm.saltedAuthenticationQuery = select password, password_salt, userId from AccountInfo where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role_name from AccountInfo_Role where accountInfo_username = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = select permission_name from Role_Permission where role_name = ?
securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO
cookie = org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
cookie.name = SSOcookie
cookie.path = /
cookie.domain = localhost
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie = $cookie
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
cacheManager.cacheManagerConfigFile = classpath:ehcache.xml
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

securityManager.sessionMode = native

#ssl.enabled=false

authc.loginUrl = /login

[urls]
/test/** = anon
/** = authc
```

The ehcache.xml file contains exactly what the stormpath site suggests in both projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
            properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                        multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                        multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=1"
            propertySeparator="," />

    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory" />

    <cache name="shiro-activeSessionCache" maxElementsInMemory="600"
           eternal="true" overflowToDisk="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" />
    </cache>

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true"
                  overflowToDisk="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

As you can see, I'm using a custom realm, but I'm pretty sure it's working properly, since the authentication part is not giving me problems at all. any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I just copied the web project and renamed it. Running the two web twin applications has the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with the jsp pages I created. I declared variables in them with session scope. That somehow was overriding the session cookie, and losing the session id.